# For loop in django views

Tags: python, django, loops, for-loop, django-views

I am a beginner.  This is my views.py code, profile_candidate is my model, refrence_mobile one of the field.  Agent is my another model which contains the list of agents,here my task is to display the list of profile_candidates in which the refernce_mobile is not matching with any of the agents available in agent table.  I tried with the code below but it is checking only the last agent in the Agent model. It is not checking all the users available in the agent model.

```py
def lead_unassigned(request):
    unassigned = Agent.objects.all()
    for i in range(0,len(unassigned)):
        team_unassigned=profile_candidate.objects.exclude(Reference_Mobile  = (unassigned[i]))

    return render(request, 'leads/lead_list_unassigned.html', 
    {'team_unassigned':team_unassigned})
```

This is my template displaying the list.  Can any one help me in achieving this?

```html
{% for i in team_unassigned %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{i.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{i.DOB}}</td>
        <td>{{i.highest_qualification}}</td>
        <td>{{i.online_exam_status}}</td>
        <td>
         
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="{% url 'lead_detail' i.pk %}">View</a>
                
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="{% url 'lead_update' i.pk %}">Update</a>
        </td>
            
          </tr>
            
        {% endfor %}
          
    </table>
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly and separate content and code.

Comment: `team_unassigned` is being overwritten each loop cycle. That is why only the last entry will be shown in template.

Answer (score 1):

Every time the loop executes, team_unassigned is given a new value, as commented by [@dgw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1137055/dgw).  You can try to use the [in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#in) method, like this:

```py
def lead_unassigned(request):
    unassigned = Agent.objects.all()
    team_unassigned=profile_candidate.objects.exclude(Reference_Mobile__in=(unassigned))

    return render(request, 'leads/lead_list_unassigned.html', 
    {'team_unassigned':team_unassigned})
```

Comment: sorry, i tried but not working

Comment: Okay, @Dlectures, but can you tell me what exactly **is** happening?  Are you getting an error?  Are you getting the wrong output?